# perl - mixture of arrays and hashes

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have the following code:

```
    my @tmpRowArr = ();
    while (my $row1 = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
      push (@tmpRowArr, $row1); 
    }
    $cached_query_hash{$uniqKey} = \@tmpRowArr;
```

Which is used to store results from a DB query into a hash ref. The has is displayed correctly. Then I want to read the values, but this does not work:

```
  my @tmpRowArr2 = $cached_query_hash{$$value{'id'}} ; 
  foreach (@tmpRowArr2){
       print $_->{id} ; 
  }
```

Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this would solve the problem:

First lines:

```
 $cached_panelists_hash{$$value{'id'}} = \@tmpRowArr;
```

Last line:

```
 my @tmpRowArr2 = @{ $cached_panelists_hash{$$value{'id'}} };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you combine your two lines

```
$cached_query_hash{$uniqKey} = \@tmpRowArr; 
...
my @tmpRowArr2 = $cached_query_hash{$$value{'id'}} ;
```

You can reduce them to

```
my @tmpRowArr2 = \@tmpRowArr;
```

Which should demonstrate why it does not work: You are assigning an array ref to an array. You need another level of dereferencing:

```
my $aref = $cached_query_hash{$$value{'id'}};
for (@$aref) {
    print $_->{id};
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I figured it out finally. See my own answer.

Comment: Yes... you took my answer and posted it as your own answer. :P You should be careful that `@tmpRowArr` goes out of scope between assignments so that several keys do not refer to the same array.